# Javascript pointer events returning coordinates with decimals

Tags: javascript

I am learning to use Javascript DOM pointer events for web applications. During the experiments, I have found out that the pointer coordinate properties such as `clientX`, `clientY`, `pageX`, `pageY`, `screenX` and `screenY` is giving values with decimal precision.

This is the code I wrote:

```html
<body style="touch-action:none;"></body>
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener("pointermove", 
    function(e) {
        this.innerHTML = "X = " + e.clientX + "<br>Y = " + 
    e.clientY;
});
</script>
```

In desktop, the screen coordinates are coming in whole numbers:
[image]
But, in mobile, the screen coordinates are coming in decimals:
[image]

To my knowledge, a pixel is the smallest unit of a screen. So, how can the coordinates be in decimals?

Comment: On mobile devices, a pixel is *not a pixel*. Take a look at [this article](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fraction of pixels in css as well. Devices (and browsers) in these cases use subpixel rendering:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I examined my PC's display resolution is 1920x1080 and the physical resolution is also 1920x1080. Whereas my phone has a resolution of 1300x600 and the physical resolution is 1080x2340. That might be the cause of this.